# Webpack + Linaria - Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app, babel-loader

I added [linaria](https://github.com/callstack/linaria/) to my webpack config in a create-react-app project, so the eventual rule is like so:

```
{
  "test": /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
  "include": "C:\\Project\\src",
  "use": [
    {
      "loader": "C:\\Project\\node_modules\\babel-loader\\lib\\index.js",
      "options": {
        "customize": "C:\\Project\\node_modules\\babel-preset-react-app\\webpack-overrides.js",
        "presets": [
          [
            "C:\\Project\\node_modules\\babel-preset-react-app\\index.js",
            { "runtime": "automatic" }
          ],
          "C:\\Project\\node_modules\\@linaria\\babel-preset\\lib\\index.js"
        ],
        "babelrc": false,
        "configFile": false,
        "cacheIdentifier": "production:babel-plugin-named-asset-import@0.3.7:babel-preset-react-app@10.0.0:react-dev-utils@11.0.4:react-scripts@4.0.3",
        "plugins": [
          [
            "C:\\Project\\node_modules\\babel-plugin-named-asset-import\\index.js",
            {
              "loaderMap": {
                "svg": {
                  "ReactComponent": "@svgr/webpack?-svgo,+titleProp,+ref![path]"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        ],
        "cacheDirectory": true,
        "cacheCompression": false,
        "compact": true
      }
    },
    {
      "loader": "C:\\Project\\node_modules\\@linaria\\webpack-loader\\lib\\index.js",
      "options": { "sourceMap": false, "cacheDirectory": "src/.linaria_cache" }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I'm getting this as a result:

> Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled

Is there anything wrong with this config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `@linaria\webpack-loader` won't work without babelrc file (even though the presets are on babel-loader already)

```
{
    "presets": [
      "babel-preset-react-app",
      "@linaria"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "babel-plugin-named-asset-import",
        {
          "loaderMap": {
            "svg": {
              "ReactComponent": "@svgr/webpack?-svgo,+titleProp,+ref![path]"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
  }
```